# count numbers (from 0 to 9) in string

Tags: c#, count

i want to count how many numbers from 0 to 9 is in string. tried some code but it don't works, it returns 0 every time. whats wrong and how to fix? also if u can tell me how do it with srting.Count() method. thanks.

```
// Attempt 1
string str = textBox1.Text;
int b = 0;
int n = 0;
foreach (char a in str)
{
    if ((b > 0) && (b < 9))
    {
        if ((char)b == a)
            n++;
    }
}
label1.Text = n;

// Attempt 2
string str = textBox1.Text;
int n = 0;
foreach (char a in str)
{
    int[] k = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    foreach (int b in k)
    {
        if (b == a)
            n += 1;
    }
}
label1.Text = n
```

Comment: The main concept that you are missing is that the number zero is a completely different thing from the symbol `0` that we use to represent that number. Your string would contain the code for the character symbol `0`, not the number zero. (And so on with the number one and the symbol `1`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a simple regex for that?

```
  var matches = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches("1 2 3 4 5 6 10 11 12", "(?<![0-9])[0-9](?![0-9])");
  Console.WriteLine(matches.Count);
```

Outputs `6`. This picks up only the isolated digits, not the ones that are part of two or more digit numbers.

EDIT: I somehow completely missed the question tag being 'c#' and wrote my original answer in python. Conveniently the actual regex pattern syntax required is the same in both python and c#.

Comment: Maybe, since the question is tagged as c#

Answer (score 6):

An example of using string.count:

`int result = "1 2 2 5 2 4".Count(char.IsDigit);`

Comment: +1 I was wondering when someone was going to suggest checking the unicode categories!

Comment: As this is a homework question I think the solution deserves a little more explanation. Here the Count() method is acting on the string as an IEnumerable<Char> sequence of individual characters. The 'Char.IsDigit' method is a predicate which effectively filters out any characters which are not digits, this you are left with a count of the characters which are digits. Worth noting that we are working with LINQ and the Char type here, not System.String directly.

Comment: thanks very much for explaining that method, but i wanted this: to count only 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9 and nothing more, such 21, 34, 56, 234 and so on... and in your case, it counts the other number too...

Answer (score 4):

With your current approach you would need to convert each character `a` from a character code into the corresponding integer. Use `Int32.Parse()`. In one of your attempts you used a `(char)b` cast but all this does is to give a character with the character code `b`.

It would be easier to write the test like this

```
foreach (char a in str)
    if ((a>='0') && (a<='9'))
        ....
```

Here I am using the syntax for a character literal, `'0'` as opposed to `"0"` which is a string literal.

Comment: i want to count only 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9 and nothing more, such 21, 34, 56, 234 and so on...

Comment: Your code samples did not indicate that. You'll need a more complex algorithm to solve that problem.

Comment: because of this i tried to use int[] k, but...
can you help and give any code? thanks for answer at any rate.

Answer (score 4):

```
int n=0;
foreach (char a in str)
{
    if (a >= '0' && a <= '9')
          n++;
}
```

Just use this.
**Explanation:**
Code of ASCII character `0` is 48 and character `9` is 57 ([here](http://www.asciitable.com/) you can find all character codes) and when you're comparing characters in C# it compares their's codes.
You could write `if (a >= 48 && a <= 57))` and it would work as well. Hope it helped.
**EDIT:**
I read your comment.

```
for(int = 1; i < str.length-1; i++)
{
    if(Char.IsDigit(str[i])) &&
       !Char.IsDigit(str[i-1]) &&
       !Char.IsDigit(str[i+1]))
        n++;
}
```

After this you should check first and last characters. That's all.

Comment: Not usually considered good form giving code solutions to homework questions, _especially_ without explanation. We have enough witless clowns in the industry already :-)

Comment: one more thing, it counts chars from 0 to 9, so when i write number 32 or something else more than 9 it counts it too...

Comment: Do you want to count digital characters in your string or count numbers like 234 or 78235? If you want to count numbers you should use regular expressions.

Comment: i want to count only 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9 and nothing more, such 21, 34, 56, 234 and so on...

Comment: you can get the char just using [] operator )) I've forgotten about it.

Answer (score 2):

This should help you

```
public int CountDigits(string text)
{
    return text.Cast<int>().Count(c => c >= 48 && c <= 57);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, the condition `if ((b > 0) && (b < 9))` is always false, because `b` starts out at zero and is never modified.

Comment: it don't works. i changed: int b = 1; and also if ((b >= 0) && (b < 9));(when b = 0) but nothing changes...

Comment: `b` is the wrong thing to be checking anyway - I think several of the other answers now explain this and provide a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Bit hard to tell how your code is sequenced but, in the first block you set `b` to 0 and never change it.

That means that `((b > 0) && (b < 9))` will always be false.

I think you should probably be checking `a` rather than `b`.

You'll also strike the problem that the *character* `'0'` is not the same as the *integer* `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "429gfsj58347583jhfs094248324";

  for(j=0;j<=9;j++)
  {
     if (str.Contains(j.ToString()))
     {
       n++;
     }
   }

Response.Write(n.ToString());


Will return the numbers frequency
Answer: 20

If you want the count separatly please ask freely.

Regards,

Madan Tiwari
```

Comment: This code can't return the answer 20 because it only goes round the loop 10 times. It is counting how many _different_ digits are in the string, not how many _total_ digits are in the string.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and LINQ wasn't available. However it was easy enough to port it the basic idea in the LINQ solution. Here's the nonLINQ solution:

```
int formatLength = 0;
foreach(char maybeDigit in format) {
           //use a ternary expression since C# can't cast bool to int
           formatLength += Char.IsDigit(maybeDigit) ? 1 : 0;
}
```